# Evaluating The Length of a Geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

Using the upper half plane model for Hyperbolic Space, the geodesic between $P=(0,1)$ and $R=(1,1)$ is the segment of the circle $C_1 :(x-1/2)^2+y^2 = 5/4$, thus solving for the length of the curve originating at $R$ and ending at $P$ is done by considering the trasformation $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1+ \sqrt{5}/2 cos\theta \\ \sqrt{5}/2 sin\theta \end{pmatrix}$ and then solving the integral $L_{C_1}= \int_R^P \sqrt{\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}}=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\sqrt{csc^2\theta \cdot d\theta^2}=ln\lvert csc \theta - cot \theta \lvert$. Solving for $csc\theta_1$ is done by considering the $(1/2 , 1, \sqrt{5}/2)$ ,triangle generated by the center of $C_1, R,$ and the projection of $R$ onto the $x-$axis. Thus, $csc \theta_1 = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $cot \theta_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and similarly, $csc \theta_2 = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $cot \theta_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. The issue I am having is that then when plugged back in to solve for the integral, I end up with value $0$, which I know is not correct.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You have 2 things to remedy: the antiderivative should be $-ln\lvert csc \theta + cot \theta \lvert$ and in the integral, there should remain a $\sqrt{5}/2$ in front of the $\sin(\theta)$... The result you should obtain is $2 \sinh^{-1}(1/2)$ using a formula that can be found in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model).

Comment: @JeanMarie I believe the two results for the indefinite integral are equivalent? And as for the constant you mention, $dx = -\sqrt{5}/2 sin \theta d\theta$ and $dy = \sqrt{5}/2 cos\theta d\theta$ and taking the squares of them and summing the up give me simply $5/4$ and this cancels out with the $5/4$ in the denominator?

Comment: All right. A last thing: $cot(\theta_2)$ should not be the same sign as $cot(\theta_1)$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Why is that so? Is it because these triangles are equivalent but the angle is take to be in the opposite orientation?

Comment: No, because one of them is less than $\pi/2$, the other one is greater. Thus $\cot$ function changes its sign.

Comment: @JeanMarie great! Thank you, the integral makes full sense now.